# React function components re-renders when anything changes

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-thunk

This react stuff is driving me nuts, I don't recall having these issues long ago with class components when I worked on react native. There must be something I'm doing wrong here, this is one of the problems I'm having, I have another component that also has a similar problem. I am new the new hook system, even reading on some stuff I'm still not very clear.

I'm running into some problems with local states and redux states that are causing my dialog to flicker. Every time the parent component set the log state in that loop, the dialog would close and open. (so in this case, 100 times depending on the loop length) It is getting re-rendered every time the state gets updated.

libraries react/redux/redux-thunk/material-ui

Sample Code

```
function ToolbarModal(props){
 const [progressLog, setProgressLog] = useState("");

 const openProgressDialog = useSelector(getOpenProgressDialog);
 const handleCloseLongProgressDialog = () => {
   dispatch(handleOpenBatchRouteProgressDialog(false))
 }

 const handleSomeLogic = () => {
  for(let i=0; i<0; i++){
    //The real one is concated with prev message
   setProgressLog("SAMPLE MESSAGE")
  }
 }

 return (
  <div>
   <LongProgressDialog
     open={openProgressDialog}
     onClose={handleCloseLongProgressDialog}
     onEntered={handleSomeLogic}
     log={progressLog}
   />
  </div>
 )
}
```

The log prop gets passed to the child component using material-ui's dialog component and just displayed in a textfield.

```
function LongProgressDialog(props){
    const {open, onClose, onEntered, log} = props

    return (
        <Dialog
            open={open}
            onClose={onClose}
            onEntered={onEntered}
            maxWidth='sm'
            fullWidth
        >
            <DialogTitle>Long Progress</DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent>
                <TextField 
                 multiline
                 fullWidth
                 rows={10}
                 rowsMax={10}
                 variant='outlined'
                 disabled
                 value={log}
                 />
            </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
    )
}
```

Comment: every time you call `setProgressLog`, you change the state variable and component re-renders. That is how a react component works. Why do you use a state variable if you don't want component to re-render?

Comment: is there a way I only re-render the textfield inside LongProgressDialog, instead of it also re-renders the parent? Because I am trying to re-direct the message from that logic function to slowly buildup the log.

Comment: no, if textfield is inside LongProgressDialog, then LongProgressDialog has to rerender too.  Though from there you could use the likes of `React.memo` on some of the child components inside LongProgressDialog to stop _them_ from rerendering unneccessarily (depending on what props they are receiving)

Comment: When you change state, components re-render but in you example I think this is not the problem. If your dialogbox flicking this may be a problem in your LongProgressDialog component. I think you should share the component too. If the openProgressDialog variable changes when you use the setprograss function, there may be a problem with the reducer.

Comment: @hasankzl updated. the reducer is only a getter from the UI slice, simple false/true

Comment: You should add forwardRef to LongProgressDialog, return something like changeText function .Then in ToolbarModal,  call changeText in useRef object of LongProgressDialog

Comment: @Slodin Your `handleSomeLogic` makes no sense, I guess that is what causes many re renders and using ref that you mutate is not a good idea if you want to re render when things change. You say you are using useCallback but I don't see that in your question, if you want good help your question should have the code that you are actually using. I think that if `handleSomeLogic` causes too many updates you can re write it with: `useCallback` to something like `const handleSomeLogic = useCallback(() => {
  setProgressLog(
    currentValue=>???.reduce(...)
  )
  },[])`

Comment: @gumingfeng thanks man for that idea! I thought there should be something that can call a child's functions!...read up on forwardref and yeah I think this is what I want. If you write it as an answer I can accept it, I got it working under 10 mins.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

gu mingfeng has answered his in his comment.
Just use a forward ref fixed my problem, this is technically what I have been looking for the entire time and didn't know it existed.

if anyone needs it, just follow the doc of forward ref from the react docs and it's very straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

Every time the reference of an object that you pass as property changes, the FC (function component) will re-render.
So, to prevent that, the props you pass must have the same reference on each re-render.

Let me explain in more detail:

For example, here:

```js
const handleSomeLogic = () => {
//...
```

you are creating a new function *every time* the FC is re-rendering (which is happening when you update state).

You can memorize the function with [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback).

Function, objects (and arrays) are changing their value everytime you create them, so:

```js
const function1 = () => {}
const function2 = () => {}
function1 === function2 // false

const emptyObj = {}
const emptyObj2 = {}
emptyObj === emptyObj2 // false

// ... etc
```

In order to memorize values, you should use the [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) hook.

So, as a solution: wrap all your function with `useCallback`.
*Note:* I can see that you are passing a progress value to the `LongProgressDialog` component, so technically every time you update the progress the `LongProgressDialog` component will re-render.

In addition to that, you should wrap your component with [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo).
When the parent re-renders the child will re-render too. React.memo prevents that and will only re-render the component when one of its props have been changed.

#### Investigating which prop is causing the issue

To find out which prop you are passing is causing the re-rendering you can compare the references of the passed props in your component, in your case the `LongProgressDialog` component.

So, for example:

```js
// create variables outside of the FC in which we will store the reference
let prop1Ref;
let prop2Ref;

const LongProgressDialog = ({ prop1, prop2 }) => {

  // for each prop, use a effect which will be called when the prop's value/reference changes
  useEffect(() => {
    // compare the values by reference
    if (prop1Ref !== prop1) {
      // when prop ref has a value, the reference must have been changed:
      if(prop1Ref != null) {
        console.log("The reference of prop1 has changed. Memorize it properly");
      }
      prop1Ref = prop1;
    }
  }, [prop1])


}
```

You can copy the logic and apply it to all of your props.
If you don't want to check it manually there are convenience libraries like https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render

Comment: I did wrap all my functions in useCallback, but they didn't seem to do anything different. The thing is, even if I don't pass the progress value into my LongProgressDialog component, as soon as I update the state using setProgressLog, it will re-render which causes the dialog to close and open.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code of what `getOpenProgressDialog` does. I suspect that the return value of this isn't memorized.

You can additionally try to wrap `LongProgressDialog` with `React.memo`.
I will edit my answer how you can further investigate which prop is causing the rerendering.

Comment: getOpenProgressDialog is only returning a true/false value from the redux slice. A simple get method. const getOpeProgressDialog = state => state.ui.openProgressDialog

Comment: okay, this is fine. Check my updated answer then, looks like you need to investigate further what's going on

Comment: I used your log. The open true/false reducer only gets changed when the value actually changed. So this reducer is working correctly...

Comment: how about the functions that you pass? Have your wrapped the LongProgressDialog with React.memo yet?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to use is [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref):

```
import { useRef } from 'react'

const Component = props => {

  const logRef = useRef()
  const handleSomeLogic = () => {
  for(let i=0; i<100; i++){
    logRef.current = "SAMPLE MESSAGE"
  }
 }
}
```

Then, pass the ref to the child component:

```
 <LongProgressDialog
     open={openProgressDialog}
     onClose={handleCloseLongProgressDialog}
     onEntered={handleSomeLogic}
     log={logRef.current}
   />
```

And in your child component:

```
const LongProgressDialog = ({open, onClose, onEntered, log}) => {

  ...
  return (
      <p> Log value is: {log} </p>
     
   )
}
```

### However,

Note that since the component doesn't get re-rendered, you won't see the updates in the child unless the component is rendered. So, you have to decide based on your case, whether you should update the state, or update the ref and re-render then. You can checkout an [example codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-mirzakhani-vhfkt?file=/src/App.js) here.

Comment: It probably could work, but as you mentioned it needs to be notified to update the ui when it changes. I'd like to keep on seeing if I could make it work with states.

Comment: Then there is no way but re-rendering the state. React can't update a value and render the updated value into a jsx without re-rendering.